# Verify mocked service call with ArgumentCaptor fails

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

In a test I use a mocked service. I want to check that the service was called once with a specific attribute of one of the parameters.
However, the method is also called mutiple times with other parameters, but I am only interested in the one call above.

My intention was to verify the call with an argument captor to check that the call of interest is invoked only once.
However this fails, because the method is called multiple times and the argument captor is checked afterwards.

See example below:

```
// service method
void serviceMethod(String someString, MyType myType);

// parameter type
class MyType {
  private String id;
  ...
  String getID() {
    return id;
  }
}

// test verification
ArgumentCaptor<MyType> paramCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(MyType.class);
// fail in verify 
Mockito.verify(serviceMock, times(1)).serviceMethod(eq("someConstantValue"), paramCaptor);
assertEquals("123", paramCaptor.getValue().getID());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the problem with a hamcrest `Matcher`. A matcher checks the parameter value when the method call is verified, whereas an argument captor only reads the parameter for later evaluation. 
In this case all other calls having an unspecified value are filtered out.

```
static Matcher<MyType> typeIdIs(final String id) {
  return new ArgumentMatcher<MyType>() {
    @Override
    public boolean matches(Object argument) {
      return id.equals(((MyType)argument).getID());
    }
  };
}

Mockito.verify(serviceMock, times(1)).serviceMethod(eq("someConstantValue"), argThat(typeIdIs("123")));
```

Comment: This is a great way to do it. In general, argument captors are an anti-pattern. You should be able to solve this with the parameters via verify.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that using a combination of `atLeastOnce()` and `getAllValues()`:

```
MyService service = mock( MyService.class );
ArgumentCaptor<MyType> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass( MyType.class );

service.serviceMethod( "foo", new MyType( "123" ) );
service.serviceMethod( "bar", new MyType( "312" ) );
service.serviceMethod( "baz", new MyType( "231" ) );

verify( service, atLeastOnce() ).serviceMethod( anyString(), captor.capture() );
List<String> ids = captor.getAllValues().stream().map( MyType::getId ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
assertThat( ids ).contains( "123" );
```

Note that I'm using [static imports](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html) as well as [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/) assertions and matchers, but you should be able to easily map this to JUnit or something else.

**EDIT:** If you want to ensure that there's exactly one occurrence of `"123"`, you could use `Collections#frequency( Collection, Object )`:

```
assertThat( Collections.frequency( ids, "123" ) ).isEqualTo( 1 );
```

Or even better: have a look at AssertJ [conditions](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/assertj-core-conditions.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answear. Never thought about collection all values for a later check. I solved the problem with a hamcrest matcher.

Comment: @Stefan You're welcome. Added an alternative approach to ensure that the ID occurs only once.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Mockito 2 with Java 8, there's a neat way of doing this. See http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/Mockito.html#36

The example would be refactored as:

```
// service method
void serviceMethod(String someString, MyType myType);

// parameter type
class MyType {
  private String id;
  ...
  String getID() {
    return id;
  }
}

// using a Java 8 lambda to test the ID within a custom ArgumentMatcher
// passed to argThat
// Note: you don't need to say "times(1)" as this assumes 1 time
// times(1) in the argument captor version would also confuse things 
// if you had other calls and you
// were just checking for whether a call like THIS had happens    
Mockito.verify(serviceMock).serviceMethod(eq("someConstantValue"), 
        argThat(input -> input.getID().equals("123")));
```

The lambda makes it cleaner, but you need Java 8 and Mockito 2.

Answer (score -1):

EDIT:

I am not aware of a way to do exactly what you are asking.

I like @beatngu13 answer.

But, *one other option* is perhaps combine use of the atLeastOnce() with an ordered verification:

```
InOrder inOrder = inOrder(serviceMock);
inOrder.verify(serviceMock, atLeastOnce()).serviceMethod(eq("someConstantValue"), paramCaptor);
inOrder.verify(serviceMock).serviceMethod(eq("someConstantValue"), fakeParamOne);
inOrder.verify(serviceMock).serviceMethod(eq("someConstantValue"), fakeParamTwo);

assertEquals("123", paramCaptor.getValue().getID());
```

where you create a fakeParam object that looks something like your param for the other calls to the service.

Comment: I wanted to verify that the service was called only *once* with the specified parameter set.